# Can't launch my Flutter application on an iPhone device

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I can't launch my Flutter application on iPhone although it launches well on iOS emulator and Android emulator/devices

XCode: v12.5.1

and here is the Android Studio complete output :

```
> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode... Legacy build system
> detected, removing
> /Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
> Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified
> development team in Xcode project: VU929CKC2Q Running Xcode build...
> Xcode build done.                                                     
>                                 59,3s Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
>         2021-11-29 13:07:45.010 xcodebuild[92092:2943731]    DVTAssertions: Warning in
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-18108/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
>         Details:    (null) deviceType from 00008030-0008252C0185402E was NULL when -platform called.
>         Object:      <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7fafa1b7f0c0>
>         Method:      -platform
>         Thread:      <NSThread: 0x7faf9ef4f360>{number = 3, name = (null)}
>         Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
>         ** BUILD FAILED **
> 
> 
> Xcode's output: ↳
>         note: Using new build system
>         note: Building targets in parallel
>         note: Planning build
>         note: Analyzing workspace
>         note: Constructing build description
>         note: Build preparation complete
>         /Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set
> to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0
> to 14.5.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
>         /Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set
> to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0
> to 14.5.99. (in target 'MTBBarcodeScanner' from project 'Pods')
>         error: Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
>         Cycle details:
>         → Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app
>         ○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app'
> to
> '/Users/truc/StudioProjects/truc/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Runner.app'
> 
> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
> 
> Error launching application on iPhone.
```

Comment: Try changing your deployment target in Runner and POD file.